# How to find total filesize grouped by extension

Tags: find, ls, disk-usage

I work on a cluster shared with other colleagues. The hard disk is limited (and has been full on some occasions), so I clean up my part occasionally. I want to do this quickly, so until now I do this by making a list of files larger than 100 MB older than 3 months, and I see if I still need them.

But now I am thinking that there could be a folder with >1000 smaller files that I miss, so I want to get an easy way to see if this is the case. From the way I generate data, it would help to get a list of total size per extension. In the context of this question, 'extension' as everything behind the last dot in the filename.

Suppose I have multiple folders with multiple files:

```
folder1/file1.bmp   40 kiB
folder1/file2.jpg   20 kiB
folder2/file3.bmp   30 kiB
folder2/file4.jpg    8 kiB
```

Is it possible to make a list of total filesize per file extension, so like this:

```
bmp 70 kiB
jpg 28 kiB
```

I don't care about files without extension, so they can be ignored or put in one category.

I already went through man pages of `ls`, `du` and `find`, but I don't know what is the right tool for this job...

Comment: This question wouldn't be amiss on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: @DougMcLean: you are welcome to post it there. ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On a GNU system:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '?*.*' -type f -printf '%b.%f\0' |
  LC_ALL=C gawk -F . -v RS='\0' '
    {s[$NF] += $1; n[$NF]++}
    END {
      PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
      for (e in s) printf "%15d %4d %s\n", s[e]*512, n[e], e
    }'
```

Or the same with `perl`, avoiding the `-printf` extension of GNU `find` (still using a GNU extension, `-print0`, but this one is more widely supported nowadays):

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '?*.*' -type f -print0 |
  perl -0ne '
    if (@s = lstat$_){
      ($ext = $_) =~ s/.*\.//s;
      $s{$ext} += $s[12];
      $n{$ext}++;
    }
    END {
      for (sort{$s{$a} <=> $s{$b}} keys %s) {
        printf "%15d %4d %s\n",  $s{$_}<<9, $n{$_}, $_;
      }
    }'
```

It gives an output like:

```
          12288    1 pnm
          16384    4 gif
         204800    2 ico
        1040384   17 jpg
        2752512   83 png
```

If you want `KiB`, `MiB`... suffixes, pipe to `numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B`.

`%b*512` gives the disk usage¹, but note that if files are hard linked several times, they will be counted several times so you may see a discrepancy with what `du` reports.

---

<sup>¹ As an exception, on HP/UX, the block size reported by `lstat()`/`stat()` is 1024 instead of 512. GNU `find` adjusts for that so it's `%b` still represents the number of 512 byte units, but with `perl`, you'd need to multiply by 1024 instead there.</sup>

Comment: Fails on MacOS (find: -printf: unknown primary or operator)

Comment: @MichaelCodes, yes `-printf` is specific to GNU `find`, which is why I said _on a GNU system_.

Comment: @MichaelCodes, see edit with a `perl` alternative that should work even on macOS.

Comment: What is 1,4,2,17? The ammount of files for each type?

Answer (score 10):

Here is another solution:

```
find . -type f |  egrep -o "\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" | sort -u | LC_ALL=C xargs -I '%' find . -type f -name "*%" -exec du -ch {} + -exec echo % \; | egrep "^\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$|total$" | uniq | paste - -
```

The part that gets the extensions is:

```
find . -type f |  egrep -o "\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" | sort -u
```

Next search for the files with an extension and print it on the screen as well:

```
LC_ALL=C xargs -I '%' find . -type f -name "*%" -exec du -ch {} + -exec echo % \;
```

Next we want to keep the extension and the total:

```
egrep "^\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$|total$" | uniq
```

and keep it on the same line:

```
paste - -
```

Comment: Works on MacOS.

Answer (score 8):

Not as nice as Stephane's solution, but you could try

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" -print0 | xargs -0r du -ch | tail -n1
```

where you have to run this for each type of files.

Comment: That assumes there are sufficiently few png files that only one `du` invocation is run. With GNU `xargs`, you'd want to add the `-r` flag so du is not run when there's no file (otherwise, you'd end up with the disk usage of the current directory). You may want to add a `-type f` or `! type d` to avoid counting the files that are in directories whose name ends in `.png`.

Comment: this only looks for one specific extension.

Comment: That's what I wrote. One had to wrap it in a script that iterates over all applicable extensions in order to get a "complete" solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since I do not yet have enough reputation points to write comments, I'll extend Stéphane Chazelas' answer here. To include in the list files with no extension, for example executables, one can use this command line:

```
find . -name '*' -type f -printf '%b.%f\0' | awk -F . -v RS='\0' '{if (NF==2) $(NF+1)=" "; s[$NF] += $1; n[$NF]++} END {for (e in s) printf "%15d %6d  %s\n", s[e]*512, n[e], e}' | sort -rn | numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B
```