# Is there a way to know percentage of images and code in a given directory?

Tags: files, disk-usage, size

Let's say you download some .zip/tar.gz or source-code of a project from somewhere. The result you will get are a random bunch of files, some having code and some having images. Is there a way to get some understanding how much percentage images, media files and how much is a text file ? If there is a tool which does that, please share. If not, how would one go in crafting a script or something which does that ?

Update - giving more information due to comments received.

Just to state an example, this is what I'm talking about -

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~/games/I-Nex] - [10054]
└─[$] [$] ll -h

total 236K
drwxr-xr-x 3 shirish shirish 4.0K 2016-11-13 21:25 debian
drwxr-xr-x 3 shirish shirish 4.0K 2016-11-13 19:16 I-Nex
drwxr-xr-x 2 shirish shirish 4.0K 2016-11-13 19:16 JSON
drwxr-xr-x 3 shirish shirish 4.0K 2016-11-13 02:12 dists
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish 7.8K 2016-11-13 02:12 i2c_smbus.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish 1.4K 2016-11-13 02:12 i-nex.mk
drwxr-xr-x 2 shirish shirish 4.0K 2016-11-13 02:12 manpages
drwxr-xr-x 2 shirish shirish 4.0K 2016-11-13 02:12 pixmaps
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish   97 2016-11-13 02:12 release.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish  280 2016-11-13 02:12 requirements.md
-rwxr-xr-x 1 shirish shirish 1.4K 2016-11-13 02:12 changelog.awk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 shirish shirish 2.5K 2016-11-13 02:12 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish 6.6K 2016-11-13 02:12 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 shirish shirish 176K 2016-11-13 02:12 Changelog.md
```

Now while this example is simple as only pixmaps directory has the pictures/images, it doesn't tell how much space is being consumed by text files and text directories and how much by pixmaps.

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to look at the file extensions, even if it isn't a perfect solution.  Can you show us what you've done so far and where you got stuck?

Comment: percentage by bytes or by number of files? what's your criteria for image vs media vs text? (is ascii art text or image? is an animated GIF an image or media?)

Comment: @JuliePelletier while what you are saying is true, I'm trying to get sense of how the directory is structured, based on space occupied. I'll update the question so it makes more sense.

Comment: @JeffSchaller percentage by bytes, hmm... guess I need to provide more details.

Comment: Now you confused me when you say you're "trying to get sense of how the directory is structured, based on space occupied".  Directory organization can be completely irrelevant to what is inside them.

Comment: @JuliePelletier -umm.. sorry, I have updated the question with a query, maybe now it makes more sense.

Comment: @JuliePelletier - does the above make more sense or not ?

Comment: You could use `file` to determine the basic file type and extract the size from the file listing `ls` and sum it up based on the file's extension.  Now show us what you did so we can help you.  This site is not a free script writing service and you need to be specific on where you get stuck.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I know `file` and I know `ls`. I was thinking if there was a tool on CLI which tells things how it is. I am guessing this is something I need to do manually, using `nauilus` or `caja`

Comment: `file` _does_ "tells things how it is".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find total filesize grouped by extension](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308846/how-to-find-total-filesize-grouped-by-extension)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

find "$1" ! -type d |
while read fpath; do
    fname="${fpath##*/}"
    suffix="${fname##*.}"

    if [[ "$suffix" == "$fname" ]]; then
        suffix="(none)"
    fi

    size="$( stat --format '%s' "$fpath" )"

    printf '%s\t%d\n' "$suffix" "$size"
done |
awk '{ sz[$1] += $2 }
     END { for (s in sz) { printf("%s:\t%d\n", s, sz[s]) } }'
```

Given a directory on the command line, the above `bash` script will use `stat`<sup>1</sup> to get the size of each individual file in the directory, and below, in bytes. The while-loop also chops off the suffix for each file and outputs it together with the size of the file (in bytes).

The `awk` script<sup>2</sup> at the end will summarize and print the information.

Example, running over a directory of one of my work projects:

```
$ bash ./script.sh /home/kk/Work/Development/project/src/
c:      4559172
am:     369
h:      151369
o:      4613432
in:     42216
out:    3282712
(none): 2908962
Po:     18414
txt:    7129
```

The output may then be further filtered and formatted if need be.

Modifying this to do percentages of total size, or to use `file` to get the filetype rather than relying on the filename suffix, or to output the sizes in another unit than bytes, is left to the reader as on exercise.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The `stat` call here is tailored for GNU `stat` from the GNU coreutils package. The `stat` on OpenBSD is *totally* different.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>The `awk` script is assumed to be run by an `awk` implementation that knows about associative arrays, such as GNU `awk` or `mawk`.</sub>

Comment: `stat`- part of coreutils ? Could you edit it so the readout is in more human readable form ?

Comment: I do like it, it at least gives some more idea/indication, I could use graphviz to generate a circle graph or something after this.

Comment: @shirish Yes, `stat` appears to be part of GNU coreutils. Thanks, I'll update the text.

Comment: @shirish Now also with a tab between the columns.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a compressed archive, like a .zip file or .tgz file, you can compare the compressed size to the uncompressed size.  Binary files within the archive will tend to compress a lot less, especially image and media files (they're already compressed).  Text files compress a whole lot more (like more than %90).

I'm too hungry to do the math right now, but if your archive is "a lot" smaller than the directory it unpacks into, you've got an archive with "a lot" of text files.  If you've got an archive that's "pretty close" to the size of the directory it unpacks into, you've got an archive that's "pretty close" to all binary files.

Hope that helps

Comment: That I know as well, I am looking for more implementation-wise details. What you have shared is more of rule of thumb sort of thing.